# How to get value of "expires" parameter of access_token using Facebook PHP SDK?

Tags: facebook, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-access-token

My Facebook PHP SDK application logged in to Facebook and received access_token.

How to get the value of "expires" parameter later time using PHP SDK?

Comment: The response that has the access token need to have another parameter called *expires*. Can you please post the code you are using?

Comment: Nitzan Tomer,

I want to get value of “expires” later time, not at login time. For example, on Mon, I login to Facebook using Facebook PHP SDK. On Tue, I want to get value of “expires” using Facebook PHP SDK.

<?php
require_once("php-sdk/src/facebook.php");

$facebook = new Facebook(array(
  'appId'  => '...',
  'secret' => '...',
));

$access_token = $facebook->getAccessToken();
echo $access_token;
?>

Answer (score 2):

Facebook API provides the expires parameter along with the access_token in its response as stated here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/

> In addition to the access token (the access_token parameter), the response contains the number of seconds until the token expires (the expires parameter). Once the token expires, you will need to re-run the steps above to generate a new code and access_token, although if the user has already authorized your app, they will not be prompted to do so again. If your app needs an access token with an infinite expiry time (perhaps to take actions on the user's behalf after they are not using your app), you can request the offline_access permission.

[image]

If you're trying to get the time remaining for an access token, I don't believe Facebook even has a method via the API for you to do this. It's easier to just request a new access token, or to request an "offline_access" token which is also documented in the above reference.

Comment: How to request a new access token using Facebook PHP SDK?

Comment: offline_access is deprecating

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/offline-access-deprecation/

Answer (score 2):

To retrieve the "expires" parameter with the Facebook PHP SDK, you need to add a few lines to the base_facebook.php script provided inside the SDK:

```
//base_facebook.php
//At Line 728

if (!isset($response_params['access_token'])) {
  return false;
}

//Add these two lines here

$_SESSION['token_created_time'] = time();
$_SESSION['token_expires'] = $response_params['expires'];

return $response_params['access_token'];
```

Once your are connected with your application, you can access your "expires" parameter and the remaining time before your token expires with the following :

```
//Your "expires" parameter :
echo $_SESSION['token_expires'];

//The remaining time before your token expires :
echo $_SESSION['token_expires'] + $_SESSION['token_created_time'] - time();
```

I hope it would help.